# How ansible assign values to variables?

Tags: ansible

Let's have a playbook:

```
---
- name: testplaybook
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  vars:
    x: 'latest'
    y: '{{x.split("-SNAPSHOT")[0]}}'
  tasks:
  - name: 1st debug x, y
    debug:
      msg: 'x={{x}}, y={{y}}'
  - set_fact: x='1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  - name: 2nd debug x, y
    debug:
      msg: 'x={{x}}, y={{y}}'
```

The output is:

```
TASK [1st debug x, y] 
**************************************************************
task path: /var/tmp/test_ansible/testPlaybook.yml:17
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "x=latest, y=latest"
}

TASK [set_fact] 
****************************************************************
task path: /var/tmp/test_ansible/testPlaybook.yml:20
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts": {"x": "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT"}, "changed": false}

TASK [2nd debug x, y] 
**********************************************************
task path: /var/tmp/test_ansible/testPlaybook.yml:21
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "x=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT, y=1.0.1"
}
```

The question is, why y is changed.

When does ansible assign values to variables and does it do a reassignment in particular cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `y` hasn't changed.  The value of `y` is a Jinja template expression, `{{x.split("-SNAPSHOT")[0]}}`.  Ansible performs [lazy evaluation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-lazy-evaluation) of these expressions, so this is evaluated whenver you use `y`.  Since the value of the expression is dependent on `x`, it will evaluate to a new value if you change `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `y` to be a string, which is `{{x.split("-SNAPSHOT")[0]}}`.

Only when you actually USE the variable does all the de-referencing occur.